# Facebook OG Debugger Can't Scrape site

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

The facebook og debugger is unable to scrape www.voinstyle.ca.  I have so far tried the following solutions and none have worked. When I hit fetch new scrape information I get the following error 'Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.'

1. Changed www from cname to A record pointing to server
2. Contacted Godaddy host - nothing wrong or unique in our server setup.
3. Doublechecked robots.txt, no problems there

I copied the homepage html to a file on a different server, and facebook was able to crawl that properly, so I do not believe it is a tagging issue. Based on this I thought it was a server issue however Godaddy cannot see anything that would indicate that.

Any ideas on what it could be, or what I could try to have the site scraped properly?

The site is a Wordpress based site.

Thanks,

Comment: Edit: Apparently the header is returning a 302 redirect for the homepage, which may be the issue.....how can I figure out where this is coming from? There is nothing in the .htaccess file to indicate a redirect

Comment: I should also mention this site uses the Redux framework....

Comment: The 302 redirect is likely part of a check for whether the client accepts cookies – try to set cookie, redirect to same address, and check if cookie was send back by the client … Now if your system keeps repeating that circle if no cookies are send back by the client (and the FB scraper does not support cookies), that might easily be the cause of the problem. You will need to investigate what part of your site/system causes this redirect – and either get rid of it completely, or add an exception for the FB scraper (and possibly other tools/bots that don’t accept cookies either.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's something with the Redux Framework.

I bought a theme that uses the Redux framework and I get the same problem as you. When I disabled the Redux Framework plugin in wordpress, and tried again the facebook debugger, I got a response.

For instance, what I did was to disable redux, scrape new information at Facebook's Object debugger, so now FB knows what to render, and finally, re enabled Redux.

I know It's not ideal, but at least, while I find out a real solution, FB will show something, and not just the URL...

I'll be reporting back with any new findings.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an ssl certificate on your domain? I am not sure, but facebook have changed alot of things for developers where you now have to use ssl in order to integrate your site/app with facebook.

I think there is something wrong with the canonical tag in your html, because it still fetches some data but not all of it. In the old working cached copy, it was http://voinstyle.ca/. Its a shot in the dark, but try changing it back to

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://voinstyle.ca/" />
```

Comment: Yes, but only on checkout pages, not every page.